# Ограничение доступа JVM

Tags: java, jvm, minecraft

#### Доброго времени суток!

#### Мне необходимо ограничить доступ java программе через JVM, если это возможно.

### Что имеем:

Система, которую не хочется заражать проприетарщиной, но хочется запустить одну несвободную вещь на java, что имеет закрытый исходный код.

В идеале - соорудить файрвол и дать программе доступ только к конкретным утилитам и библиотекам.

Возможно ли такое реализовать через JVM?

- **программа** - minecraft 1.16.5
- **ОС** - artix linux
- **jre**-8-openjdk
- Не боюсь конфигов и java кода.

Джаву трогал только как язык программирования и не вникал особо в детали.

Что скажете?

Comment: Не понятно, в чем вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Andrei исправил

Comment: Ставьте виртуалу - и будет вам файервол